# Prevent inline images being attached

Tags: java, email

I have a method that sends email, the signature is:

```
public void sendEmail(String to, File[] fileAttachments, String subject, 
                        String body, boolean inlineImages) throws Exception {
```

I've recently modified it to be able to send Images inline (in the HTML email) as opposed to as attachments.
The method body that deals with attachments is:

```
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    // messageBodyPart.setText(body);
    messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    if (fileAttachments != null) {
        for( File f : fileAttachments ) {
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(f);

            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            
            if( inlineImages ) {
                messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
            } else
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(f.getName());
            
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        }
    }

    // Put parts in message
    message.setContent(multipart);

    // Send the message
    Transport.send(message);
```

Unfortunately, it now sends the images *both* inline **and** as an attachment.
How can I modify the code so it doesn't attach the image if it's inline?

Comment: Since you know whether or not you have inLineImages from the boolean in the method signature, I would assume all you need is an extra check before handling attachments:            

if ((fileAttachments != null)  &&  ! inLineImages){
}

Comment: @JoachimBülow no, the rest of the code in that block is required to get the images to display inline